# How to manage sequence of steps in Mongoid and Ruby

Tags: ruby, database-design, nosql, mongoid

I'm trying to create a `Tour` with a sequence of `Steps` in Ruby and Mongoid:

```
class Tour
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,    type: String
  embeds_many :steps
end

class Step
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,    type: String
  embedded_in :tour
end
```

**What's the best way to manage the ordered sequence of steps?** (taking into account: inserting, deleting, moving steps around)

My first reaction is to do it one-way linked list style, storing the next step:

```
class Step
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,    type: String

  embeds_one  :step, store_as: "next_step"
  embedded_in :tour
end
```

Interested if anyone else has better design advice :)

Thanks!

Comment: Using one way relationship would lead to hard maintenance if you want to change steps order. Why don't you keep embeds_many + a step order field?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @apneadiving :)

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Comment: It helps :) I usually give it a couple more days before I'll mark it as answer

Comment: @apneadiving Happy to vote this as an answer, just add it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one way relationship would lead to hard maintenance if you want to change steps order.

I recommend using embeds_many + a step order field + custom validator.

Comment: What should the custom validator do?

Comment: I'd check all entries have a different order, since these are embedded models, it won't cost much